# VS2015 VC++ Win32 application not working through IIS

Tags: c++, winapi, iis, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

VS2015 VC++ Win32 application not working through IIS

I'm trying to convert a legacy ISAPI application from VS2003 to VS2015. However, I wanted to get a simple application running before I convert the entire application.

Here are the steps I followed:

***Step 1:***

Create a new VisualC++ Win32 project ‘Web1’

***Step 2:***

Add the following code to Web1.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <HttpExt.h>

BOOL WINAPI GetExtensionVersion(HSE_VERSION_INFO* pVer)
{
    pVer->dwExtensionVersion = HSE_VERSION;
    return TRUE;
}

BOOL WINAPI TerminateExtension(DWORD dwFlags)
{
    return TRUE;
}

DWORD WINAPI HttpExtensionProc(EXTENSION_CONTROL_BLOCK *pECB) {

    char *header =
        "<html>"
        "<head>"
        "<title>Hello from Web1</title>"
        "</head>"
        "<body>"
        "<h1>Hello from Web1</h1>";

    DWORD size = static_cast< DWORD >(strlen(header));
    pECB->WriteClient(pECB->ConnID, header, &size, 0);

    char *intro = "<p>Your name is: ";
    size = static_cast< DWORD >(strlen(intro));
    pECB->WriteClient(pECB->ConnID, intro, &size, 0);
    size = static_cast< DWORD >(
        strlen(pECB->lpszQueryString));
    pECB->WriteClient(pECB->ConnID, pECB->lpszQueryString,

        &size, 0);

    char *footer =
        "</p>"
        "</body>"
        "</html>";

    size = static_cast< DWORD >(strlen(footer));
    pECB->WriteClient(pECB->ConnID, footer, &size, 0);

    return HSE_STATUS_SUCCESS;

}
```

***Step 3:***

Create Web1.def file and GetExtensionVersion, TerminateExtension and HttpExtensionProc

***Step 4:***

Set ‘:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe’ as the debuging command for the project, and ‘-debug’ as command arguments.

***Step 5:***

Create a virtual directory in IIS pointing to the directory with build output.

When I fire off a request through the browser after starting the application in debug mode, all I see in is a 500 response, with the following in the output:

```
'w3wp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Win32Project1\Win32Project1.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'w3wp.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Win32Project1\Win32Project1.dll'
```

Am I missing any obvious steps or doing something wrong? Any help/insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: could you try c:\windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe

Comment: That did the trick.... Thank you so much!